# Web-scraping data from a built in Javascript game

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, tesseract

Essentially, I'm using Python to try and get the score of a javascript game built into a website.

I've used Tesseract and Selenium so far to try and screenshot and recognise the score but I need consistency and it does stuff up the numbers sometimes. I've also tied changing Tesseract's page segmentation modes and it did improve slightly but still not giving exact numbers. For example it gives 33.7 instead of 38.7 or even = and _ symbols as the score changes.

My entire code is a bit long but in essence it takes a screenshot after each press of a key (to move the character), then displays the score. This is an example of just the screenshotting I have.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from pytesseract import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
import time

drvGame = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Program Files\chromedriver.exe")
pthTesseract = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"
pthImage = r"scrOriginal.png"
pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = pthTesseract

drvGame.get("https://www.foddy.net/ice/")
drvGame.set_window_size(width = 1000, height = 536)
time.sleep(10)
drvGame.save_screenshot("scrOriginal.png")

imgScore = Image.open(pthImage)
width, height = imgScore.size
box = 850, 0, width, height / 5

imgCropped = imgScore.crop(box)
imgCropped.save("scrCropped.png")

fltScore = pytesseract.image_to_string(imgCropped, config = "--psm 7")
fltScore = fltScore.replace("\n", "")
    
print (fltScore)
```

For context the website is 'https://www.foddy.net/ice/' and the script in the HTML source is titled './surprise.min.js'. [An 'imgCropped' example looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AYjM.png)

I'm new to web-scraping and Selenium in general so anything to help would be appreciated.